# symfony2 DI bundle service unavailable

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I've defined a service in the Resources/config/services.yml:

```
services:
    gSm.gate.terminal:
        class: Stream\TerminalBundle\StreamTerminal
        arguments: [ [], [%terminal_login%, %terminal_password%] ]
```

And I try to access in inside my controller action:

```
public function displayAction() {
    $terminal = $this->get('gSm.gate.terminal');
    return $this->render('StreamTerminalBundle::display.html.twig');
}
```

Server returns following exception: `500 You have requested a non-existent service "gsm.gate.terminal"`. The bundle is registered in the appKernel, the bundle uses .yml config files... and I don't know what else can I look at to make this service available... thanks for any help.

EDIT:

My extension class code is:

```
namespace Stream\TerminalBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */
class StreamTerminalExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're [importing the bundle's `services.yml`](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html#importing-other-container-configuration-resources). A simplest way is to [import](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html#importing-configuration-with-imports) it from `config.yml`. A better and more advanced solution is to [write an extension](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html#importing-configuration-via-container-extensions).

To see an example of an extension class, see my [bundle's one](https://github.com/elnur/ElnurBlowfishPasswordEncoderBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/ElnurBlowfishPasswordEncoderExtension.php#L34-L35). If you want to use YAML, just change `services.xml` to `services.yml` and `XmlFileLoader` to `YamlFileLoader`.

Answer (score 1):

Is your services.yml file being parsed by the Extension class?
By default in a new bundle it's setup to load the xml file.
Can you paste your

```
Acme\Bundle\YourBundle\DependencyInjection\AcmeYourExtension
```

class?

Comment: I've found the problem. I changed my bundle namespace after it has been generated and I had to fix all class and file names to fit to the naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can use uppercase letters in you service names. The exception gives such a hint "gsm.gate.terminal" while your service is "gSm.gate.terminal".